# Why am I getting 404 error making REST call to activiti-rest?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, activiti

I'm not sure whether this is a problem with Activiti or my Tomcat Server 8.0. Basically I'm starting a project that uses activiti-rest and I tested it yesterday using Advanced REST Client and it worked fine.

Today I had to import a project into my Tomcat server and with it I had to add a few jars to the Tomcat libs folder because the project used a SOAP interface. I'm providing this information as this was the last thing I done before I tested activiti-rest again and now I'm getting a 404 error every call. The jars I added are ones suggested by this tutorial: [jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/). This is the tutorial I followed to create the project I imported that had the SOAP interface.

I'm just really confused about what the problem could be. Is there a way of finding out more about the problem? I only get the basic tomcat 404 page with no extra info besides "The requested resource is not available".

EDIT: The project that involves a SOAP interface is in no way connected to the project that uses activiti-rest, I was just mentioning it as it was the last thing I done prior to REST not working.

Comment: Did you have a look in the Tomcat log files?

Comment: @hzpz all that's in the log file is "127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2015:11:35:13 +0100] "GET /activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments HTTP/1.1" 404 1082". Is there a way to get more info? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Just check if the activiti-rest application is running in the tomcat manager webapp

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure db.properties and engine.properties for both(activiti-rest and activiti-explorer)?.
And depends the version of your activiti.(db.properties and engine.properties are in version 5.16.4 and above)